# How can I get my dynamic table to update a sharepoint list with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, sharepoint

I've got it almost done although it won't add any of the rows after the first one.Here's my script:

```
     $('#submitdataAccounts').click(function(){
          $('#tableAc tbody tr').each(function(){


          var productType = $(".productType").val();
          var selectorNSC = $(".selectNsc").val();
          var accountNumber= $(".accountNumber").val();
          var spFirstNameVal= $(".spFirstName").val();
          var spSurnameVal = $(".spSurname").val();
          var spMobileVal = $(".spMobile").val();

    var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.Accounts_x005f_ListListItem' },
    "OData__x0065_c91": productType,
    "tsyh": selectorNSC,
    "OData__x0075_dm6": accountNumber,
    "fddm": spFirstNameVal,
    "n72h": spSurnameVal,
    "OData__x0066_r77": spMobileVal,

       };
         $.ajax({
                   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Accounts_List')/items",
                   method: "POST",
                                 data: JSON.stringify(data),

                            headers: { 
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), 
            },
                   success: function (data) {
                              alert('Item added successfully');
                  },
                  error: function (error) {
                      alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
                 }
          });

});


});
```

I am using a table that has its rows added in the script like so:

```
document.getElementById("tableAc").insertRow(-1).innerHTML ='<td class="style1a">' +
'<select name="productType" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle Select1" style="width:150px"><option value="" selected=""><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
<div class="divhidden" ><i><br />2nd Party Surname<i/><br /><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 150px" /></div></td><td class="style1a"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 150px"/><div class="divhidden" ><i><br />2nd Party Mobile<i/><br /><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 150px" /></div></td><td class="style1a"><input type="checkbox" style="width: 150px" class="checkboxAC"/></td><td><a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this);" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="Delete" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Delete</span></a></td>';
```

It mimics the same layout as the actual table so it just duplicates the first row when the AddRow button is pressed.

In my sharepoint list, I just see the same first row added for the amount of rows I've filled in.

Any ideas?

Also, I must point out i've 2 fields going to different places in each in each cell

thanks

edit:

It now looks like this but still does not work:

```
             $('#submitdataAccounts').on('click',function(){
                $('table tr').each(function(){


var productType = $(this).find(".productType").val();
var selectorNSC = $(this).find(".selectNsc").val();
var accountNumber= $(this).find(".accountNumber").val();
var spFirstNameVal= $(this).find(".spFirstName").val();
var spSurnameVal = $(this).find(".spSurname").val();
var spMobileVal = $(this).find(".spMobile").val();

    var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.Accounts_x005f_ListListItem' },
    "OData__x0065_c91": productType,
    "tsyh": selectNSC,
    "OData__x0075_dm6": accountNumber,
    "fddm": spFirstName,
    "n72h": spSurname,
    "OData__x0066_r77": spMobile,
       };
         $.ajax({
                   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Accounts_List')/items",
                   method: "POST",
                   data: JSON.stringify(data),
                   headers: { 
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), 
            },
                   success: function (data) {
                              alert('Item added successfully');
                  },
                  error: function (error) {
                      alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
                 }
          });
  });

});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, element with class productType, selectNsc, accountNumber, ... are cells inside rows of your table. So, to get the value of a cell, I think you should change $(".productType").val(); with $(this).find(".productType").text(); or $(this).find(".productType").html();

Comment: Sorry, here is the correct suggestion : element with class productType, selectNsc, accountNumber, ... are elements located inside cells of your table. So, to get the value of those elements, I think you should change `$(".productType").val();` with `$(this).find(".productType").val();`

Comment: Hi, thanks I'll give it a go in work tomorrow. Could this effect it only updating the first row and then not updating any of the other rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, your table contains 5 rows.

Inside the loop trough all the TR elements if you write this : `$(".productType").val();`

This JQuery will select all elements that has productType class in the entire page.

But it will return only the value of the first element that has this class.

But if you write this : `$(this).find('.productType').val();`

In this case, `$(this)` means the current TR element.

So you narrow the search to only elements that has a productType class inside the current TR element.

To see the difference, try this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#MyButton').on('click',function(){
                $('table tr').each(function(){
                    console.log($(this).find(".mySelect").val());
                    console.log($(".mySelect").val());
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="MyButton">Test</button>
        <table id="mytable">
            <tr>
                <td><select class="mySelect"><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><select class="mySelect"><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><select class="mySelect"><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I got it working. Turns out I forgot to match the classes up in the addrows

Answer (score 1):

You are always getting the first items from your loop.

Replace the variable assignments with the code below

```
var productType = $(this).find(".productType").val();
var selectorNSC = $(this).find(".selectNsc").val();
var accountNumber= $(this).find(".accountNumber").val();
var spFirstNameVal= $(this).find(".spFirstName").val();
var spSurnameVal = $(this).find(".spSurname").val();
var spMobileVal = $(this).find(".spMobile").val();
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Hi, I actually changed it to this myself originally but it didn't work. I've also tried your code now and it still is just giving me the first line

Comment: Try console.log each variable and comment out the Ajax request for now.  The f12 browser tools should log out the values.

Comment: Also your field names look strange.  Are they correct?

Comment: Doesn't matter, got it working. I forgot to update the class names in the inner HTML